# Set of MPI tags

Tags: c, mpi

Is is possible to specify a set of tags to an MPI_Recv function?

My scenario:

I'm working with an application that has multiple threads that simultaneously execute the MPI_Recv function. I intend to use the mpi tag to control which thread will receive the message. But I also need to control if the message is a *data_message* or a *stop_message*.

So, is it possible to define a set of tags for MPI_Recv?
Semantically, would be something like "Receive messages with tags 0 or 1", or "Receive messages with tags 10 or 11", etc. It must be multiple values.

Using this approach would be possible to use the tags *thread_id*2* as *data_message* and *thread_id*2+1* as a *stop_message*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather use an empty message (`MPI_Send(count = 0)`) to signal the stop condition in your case. Simply wait for a matching message with `MPI_Probe(tag = thread_id)` and then use `MPI_Get_count` on the returned status object to determine the message size. Should it happen to be zero, break the processing loop.

Another option is to have each thread communicate in a separate communicator. Use `MPI_Comm_dup` to create an array of duplicates of `MPI_COMM_WORLD` and then have thread *i* communicate in `comms[i]`. You can then utilise `MPI_Recv(tag = MPI_ANY_TAG, comm = comms[i])` to match messages with any tag and that will be thread-specific. On the sender side, use `MPI_Send(rank = dest, comm = comms[i])` to address thread *i* of rank *dest*.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct function to match a specific set of tags (since `MPI_TAG_ANY` would be inappropriate here due to non-specificity), but there is a way to accomplish the same goal. Post two `MPI_Irecv` requests in each thread, one for each tag you want to match. Then use `MPI_waitany` or `MPI_Testany` to see what comes in.

Comment: `MPI_Testany` and `MPI_Waitany` are sources of non-determinism. It will only work if the OP can guarantee that no _stop_message_ will be sent before the reception of the preceding _data_message_ has been somehow guaranteed.

Comment: That's a good point. My suggestion depends on only one or the other of those messages actually being available to match, since the ordering semantics won't help between different specified tags on different receives.